# Pig Script: Join with multiple files

Tags: join, apache-pig, bigdata

I am reading a big file (more than a billion records) and joining it with three other files, I was wondering if there is anyway the process can be made more efficient to avoid multiple reads on the big table.The smalltables may not fit in memory.

```
A = join smalltable1 by  (f1,f2) RIGHT OUTER,massive by (f1,f2) ;
B = join smalltable2 by  (f3) RIGHT OUTER, A by (f3) ;
C = join smalltable3 by  (f4) ,B by (f4) ;
```

The alternative that I was thinking is to write a udf and replace values in one read, but I am not sure if a udf would be efficient since the small files won't fit in the memory. The implementation could be like:

```
A = LOAD massive 
B = generate f1,udfToTranslateF1(f1),f2,udfToTranslateF2(f2),f3,udfToTranslateF3(f3)
```

Appreciate your thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig 0.10 introduced integration with Bloom Filters http://search-hadoop.com/c/Pig:/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/Bloom.java%7C%7C+%2522done+%2522exec+Tuple%2522

You can train a bloom filter on the 3 smaller files and filter big file, hopefully it will result in a smaller file. After that perform standard joins to get 100% precision.

**UPDATE 1**
You would actually need to train 2 Bloom Filters, one for each of the small tables, as you join on different keys.

**UPDATE 2**
It was mentioned in the comments that the outer join is used for augmenting data. 
In this case Bloom Filters might not be the best thing, they are good for filtering and not adding data in outer joins, as you want to keep the non matched data. A better approach would be to partition all small tables on respective fields (f1, f2, f3, f4), store each partition into a separate file small enough to load into memory. Than Group BY massive table on f1, f2, f3, f4 and in a FOREACH pass the group (f1, f2, f3, f4) with associated bag to the custom function written in Java, that loads the respective partitions of the small files into RAM and performs augmentation.

Comment: Thanks alexeipab. Your solution for optimization of pig group join for distinct values had worked for me.. so i believe this will work too.. I will update the post once I implement this.

Comment: You would actually need to train 2 Bloom Filters, one for each of the small tables, as you join on different keys.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of the outer join in you case? Is it to add extra columns to the massive table or to get rows that do not match to the small tables?

Comment: To add the extra columns wherever information available. Then I have to group by and get the total.

Comment: I have updated the question. There are actually 3 small tables and those are not enough to fit in memory. One small table has about 30M records but only 3M are in use, but we don't know which 3M beforehand.

Comment: In this case Bloom Filters might not be the best thing, they are good for filtering and not adding data in outer joins, as you want to keep the non matched data. A better approach would be to partition all small tables on respective fields (f1, f2, f3, f4), store each partition into a separate file small enough to load into memory. Than Group BY massive table on f1, f2, f3, f4 and in a FOREACH pass the group (f1, f2, f3, f4) with associated bag to the custom function written in Java, that loads the respective partitions of the small files into RAM and performs augmentation.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable... I will implement this way and will post the performance...

Comment: For future readers, I replaced smaller tables with Redis and am satisfied with the performance. Thanks Alexeipab for support.