# join file A,B,C in hadoop

Tags: join, hadoop, apache-pig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pig Script: Join with multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390252/pig-script-join-with-multiple-files)

I do a program based on hadoop.
Now, I have three file A,B,C. And I want to join them and following the condition "A.one = B.one and A.two = C.one";Then store the result to file D.

I know a little about pig, but its join can't content this command.

Comment: I don't understant. What do you mean by "A.one" ?

Comment: I don't know how to express exactly, it like this sql: select * from A,B,C where A.one = B.one and A.two = C.otherone.   And I know something about pig multiple files join, but it can satisfy that using different column and different number of columns in relations.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is easy in Pig as two step join:

```
A=LOAD ..
B=LOAD ..
C=LOAD ..

AB= JOIN A BY A.one,B BY B.One;
D= JOIN AB BY A::two, C BY C.one;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. In fact I have more than three file, if I do it like this, I will process a lot of join-operations. could you give me other options

Comment: How do you think it is going to happen when there are a lot of large files you're going to join? If one or more of the files are small you can hint pig with USING 'replicated' and it will hold that table in memory

Comment: I know pig join using keyword 'replicated',but this function can only satisfied the condition A.one = B.one = C.one; However, I want different columns in A such as one,two. As above A.one = B.one and A.two = C.one